# Show that a process is MA(3)

Tags: lags, moving-average

Let $X_t$ be a MA(1) time series - i.e., there is an IID  $N(0,\sigma)$ process, 
$Z_t$, such that: (for some value $\theta$) $X_t = Z_t + \theta Z_{t−1}$ for $t= \cdots , -3, -2, -2, 0, 1, 2, 3, \cdots$

Suppose that we don’t get to observe the $X_t$ process, but rather $Y_t$ defined as: 
$$Y_t = (a +b t+c t^2) + X_t$$

Show that the process $W_t$ defined by second-differencing:

$W_t = \nabla^2 Y_t$ is a MA process, like $X_t$, but is MA(3)  (as opposed to MA(1)  - as a result of second-differencing).

I have no idea how to even start. I've read over every example in this chapter of the textbook, and all I can get from it is:

$W_t = Y_t - 2 Y_{t-1} + Y_{t-2}$, so that leads to:
$$W_t =((a +bt +ct^2) + X_t) - 2((a + b(t-1) + c(t-1)^2) + X_{t-1}) + ((a + b(t-2) + c(t-2)^2) + X_{t-2}$$

After that, I don't really understand how any of that progresses...

Comment: Please use Latex (MathJax http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference ) for formatting math expressions.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to note is that the second difference of the process $S_t = (a+b t+ct^2)$ is a constant: $\nabla^2 S_t = 2 c$

Then, by linearity of the difference operator, $W_t = \nabla^2 Y_t = 2c +  \nabla^2 X_t$

Now, the (single) difference operator $\nabla$ is a MA filter of order 1, hence the  $\nabla^2$ is a MA filter of order 2, and hence $\nabla^2 X_t$ is a MA(3) process.

$W_t$ is then the sum of a zero mean $MA(3)$ process plus a constant - which can also be regarded as a MA(3) process, but generated by a white noise of non-zero mean.